# imovie picture-in-picture remove bottom border

Tags: imovie

I have a white movie clip that I am embedding inside a white background as picture-in-picture.  Although I have no border selected, the movie clip retains a small border on the bottom.  How do I ensure there is absolutely no border in the clip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to crop your source video, which is quite simple to do. Here is a screenshot showing approximately what you're working with:

[image: exposition]

To crop the clip, first select the clip in the timeline. Then, click the [image: crop] icon above the video preview, select "Crop to Fill", and resize the rectangle as desired. To prevent it from snapping to the borders, hold the Command key as you drag. Below is an example of what this might look like—though I've cropped it much more than you will, most likely.

[image: instructions]

Finally, here's what it should look like (I've selected the picture-in-picture tool to demonstrate the bounding box of the clip):

[image: ta-da]

Comment: Can I resize it vertically, but not horizontally?  I just want to cut off the horizontal stripe on the bottom.

Comment: @WalrustheCat I believe it is constrained to the aspect ratio of the project, and there is no way around it within iMovie. If it's important to preserve the details on the other three edges, you could crop the video in another program and re-import it, or you could edit the whole thing in something more advanced (e.g. Final Cut or Premiere). I'm pretty sure those are your only options.

Comment: OTY!!!!!!!!!!!!